# Freestyle lines & grease pencil objects 2.8 - how can I stop freestyle from rendering in front of grease pencil objects?

Tags: grease-pencil, freestyle

When I have a 3D mesh object in the background, freestyle enabled, and then a grease pencil object in the foreground, then press F12 to render, the freestyle lines are drawn in front of the grease pencil object, even though the object is in front of the 3D mesh object. How can I get freestyle to not render in front of the grease pencil object?

[image]
[image]

Comment: check this out: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/158054/rendering-freestyle-along-with-grease-pencil