# Freestyle rendering in EEVEE show's up on top of other greace pencil objects, how do i fix it?

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine, grease-pencil, freestyle

When I activate the Freestyle setting in the render tab for my 3D objects and render it, the render of the lines are on top of my other grease pencil objects and intersects them in an unwanted way. Is there a way to fix this? i've tried to change the origin point for all of the  3D and 2D objects but that did not fix it. Sorry if i'm not explaining the problem well, I'm happy to try and explain more.

I'm using Blender 2.93(beta) and the freestyle has a noise and a thickness modifier.

thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/158054/rendering-freestyle-along-with-grease-pencil?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can imagine why this is happening: Grease Pencil is not considered by Freestyle at all. Thankfully, you can change freestyle to be “as render pass,” put the grease pencil objects on a separate view layer, and composite the Grease Pencil over the freestyle over the main view layer.

Comment: Thank you for the help!

Comment: @Hipple Your welcome. PTL! 